# Why doesn't Inkscape correctly read PDF files generated by R?

Tags: r, pdf, svg, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

Very often, I draw graphs in R and export them in pdf or svg. Then I import them in Inkskape or Illustrator. Sometimes this generates weird results. For instance, when I generate a simple scatterplot with shapes (1 and 16), Inkscape in unable to read it and generate the following [file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pachevalier/6f9ea02430609536da5e/raw/test.svg). See my [gist file](https://gist.github.com/blaquans/6f9ea02430609536da5e#file-sample-r). I suspect that this should be due to the default options of the `pdf()` graphics device but I'm not sure. Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: Well, what happens if you change the defaults for `pdf()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a symptom of different fonts being used as the plotting symbols. Try creating the PDF file using:

```
   pdf("test.pdf", useDingbats = F) 
   plot(1:10, 10:1, pch=16 )
   dev.off()
```

Screenshot from Inkscape
[image: Screenshot from Inkscape]

There is a long "Note" in `?pdf` about why the authors of R think some pdf viewers (apparently Inkscape being one such)  are failing  and some configuration suggestions which I have not tested on my Mac.