# Rstudio pdf export imported in Inkscape

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, inkscape, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export pdf of ggplot-generated figures for post-processing in Inkscape using various methods: ggsave(), pdf(), dev.copy2pdf() and Rstudio export via GUI (3x3 size).

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,10,1),
                 y = seq(1,10,1),
                 y.err = rep(1,10))

p<- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - y.err, ymax = y + y.err))+
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "white")

ggsave(p, file = "ggsave.pdf", width = 3, height = 3)

pdf(file = "pdf.pdf", width = 3, height = 3)
p
dev.off()

p

dev.copy2pdf(file = "dev.copy2pdf.pdf", width = 3, height = 3)
```

All pdf files look similar in Adobe Reader with GUI-generated file somewhat bigger (5.2 kb vs. 4.8 kb). [Screenshot-1](http://image.prntscr.com/image/ba66b1c450b44fafb526ada363c8cf86.png)

But when imported to Inkscape, three non-GUI generated plots have circles for data points of smaller radius and misaligned (see [Screenshot-2](http://image.prntscr.com/image/25ec4e8ac39e434ebf6c9730c0e65e29.png)).

Does anybody know what are parameters that I'm missing in pdf export commands to get the same result in the Inkscape import? Thanks

Additional info:

- OS Windows 10
- Rstudio 0.99.441
- R 3.2.4
- Inkscape 0.91

[update 1] . Updated Rstudio to 0.99.902; R to 3.3.0. Same issue.

[solution] Addition `useDingbats = F` to any pdf-exporting command solves the issue (taken from [Why doesn't Inkscape correctly read PDF files generated by R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524262/why-doesnt-inkscape-correctly-read-pdf-files-generated-by-r?rq=1))

Comment: I think at the very least, we need OS info, R & Rstudio Version, etc.

Comment: I can't replicate on ubuntu 14.04, R 3.3.0, ggplot 2.0

Comment: Thank you for the comments, added the additional info to the question

Comment: Might be a font embedding issue. You could try running `grDevices::embedFonts` on the files and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that was font problem, solved using this post solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524262/why-doesnt-inkscape-correctly-read-pdf-files-generated-by-r?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Addition `useDingbats = F` to any pdf-exporting command solves the issue (taken from [Why doesn't Inkscape correctly read PDF files generated by R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524262/why-doesnt-inkscape-correctly-read-pdf-files-generated-by-r?rq=1))