# Color Gradient Issue when Importing PDF into Inkscape

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, vector-graphics, inkscape

I am making a figure with a colorbar in R, which I am importing into InkScape for annotations, etc. My workflow is to create the figure in R, save it as a PDF, and import that PDF into InkScape. However, when I import the PDF into InkScape, the colorbar of the figure gets changes from just a vertical gradient to a vertical + horizontal gradient.

To illustrate, here is the colorbar in the raw PDF file:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when I import it into InkScape:

[image]

The central axis looks correct, but the lateral gradient is incorrect.

If I export the image from R as a PNG file and then import it into InkScape using the same procedure, the colorbar imports correctly. Therefore, it seems that the issue is related to vectorized graphics. However, I would prefer to keep the image in vectorized format to preserve quality at different resolutions.

The rest of the plot (including the raster that uses the color gradient) looks normal upon import; the only problem is the colorbar.

Does anyone know how to preserve color gradients when importing a PDF into InkScape?

For reference, here is the code I am using to create the PDF in R:

```
pdf(paste0(path.fig, "Figure_HeatMaps_NoText.pdf"), width=(190/25.4), height=(190/25.4), useDingbats=F)
grid.arrange(
  grid.arrange(p.dd.years + theme(text=element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,8,4,0.5), "mm")), 
               p.dd.diff + theme(text=element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,8,4,0.5), "mm")), 
               ncol=2, widths=c(0.8, 1), newpage=F),
  grid.arrange(p.MaxTSA.years + theme(text=element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(4,8,0.5,0.5), "mm")), 
               p.MaxTSA.diff + theme(text=element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(4,8,0.5,0.5), "mm")), 
               ncol=2, widths=c(0.8, 1), newpage=F),
  ncol=1, newpage=F)
dev.off()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662120/rstudio-pdf-export-imported-in-inkscape) seems peripherally related; however, setting `useDingbats=F` in my PDF export does not fix the problem.

Comment: have you tried `raster = FALSE` in `guide_colourbar()`? I suspect it might have something to do with it.

Comment: @baptiste - Including `guide=guide_colorbar(raster=F)` in my call to `scale_fill_gradient` solved the problem, though it did transform the scale from a continuous color gradient into a series of bins. Fortunately I have no problem with bins so I'm happy to accept this as an answer if you'd like. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you can tune the number of breaks with `nbin`