# ggplot PDF import to Inkscape adds extra hollow circles to geom_point dots when using alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2, inkscape

How to prevent `Inkscape` from adding extra circles to `geom_point()` dots when using `alpha` (transparency) when importing a `ggplot` figure in `.pdf` format?

## Make figure:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg)) + geom_point(alpha=0.5)
```

### Save as PDF:

```
ggsave('inkscape_bug.pdf')
```

I get these perfectly smooth semi-transparent circles (zoomed screenshot of resulting `.pdf` file):

[image]

But when I export to `Inkscape`, in addition to the semi-transparent full circles also appear smaller and darker hollow circles on top:

[image]

**Tried:** This is probably a duplicate (I can't believe no one else has had this problem before) but I can't find the right keywords to find the correct threads. [The only thing I can find is to add `useDingbats=FALSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524262/why-doesnt-inkscape-correctly-read-pdf-files-generated-by-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), but even that doesn't fix this issue.

I also tried changing the options when importing to `Inkscape` (`Popper/Cairo import`, `Internal import`, [unchecked] `Replace PDF fonts by closest-named installed fonts` and `Embed images`), to no avail. Interestingly, I get the same result directly (without exporting to `Inkscape` or any other software) if I save as `.svg` instead of `.pdf`. Weird isn't it?

**Question:** 1) Why does it do that? 2) How to prevent it?

Comment: have you tried pch=16?  On my system, the default pch seems to be 19, which has a border.

Comment: Hey, just tried this and seems like it did the trick! Documentation says pch = 16, filled circle and pch = 19, solid circle, but I don't quite get the nuance, especially if we use the same colours (they look the same in the examples). I also don't understand why when exporting to PDF they look the same but just not when exported in another software?

Comment: I just confirmed that default shape is 19.  (ggplot2 environment - GeomPoint>default_aes).  I regularly use variable alpha and never use the default because it looks terrible.  16 for solid and 21 for variable fill with a border.

Comment: Also, you might want to save the plot using `ggsave()` and use `device = "svg"` to avoid importing artifacts.
Seems like PDF might be interpreting both point types as just one type when doing the rasterization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shape = 16` in your geom_point.  The default ggplot point shape is 19, which has a border.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone using the `ggsave` command to export .png images from `ggplot2`: Dan Slone's answer above solves a similar problem with "bordered" points when alpha < 1. Use `shape = 16`.

Comment: This answer would be better suited as a comment to the referenced answer, not as a separate answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30211740)